# Anomalous MPI behavior

Tags: mpi

I am wondering if anyone can offer an explanation.

I'll start with the code:

```c
/*
Barrier implemented using tournament-style coding
*/

// Constraints: Number of processes must be a power of 2, e.g.
// 2,4,8,16,32,64,128,etc.

#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void mybarrier(MPI_Comm);

// global debug bool
int verbose = 1;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int rank;
    int size;

  int i;
  int sum = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int check = size;

    // check to make sure the number of processes is a power of 2
    if (rank == 0){
        while(check > 1){
            if (check % 2 == 0){
                check /= 2;
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: The number of processes must be a power of 2!\n");
                MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // simple task, with barrier in the middle
  for (i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    sum ++;
  }
  mybarrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  for (i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    sum ++;
  }

    if (verbose){
        printf("process %d arrived at finalize\n", rank);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void mybarrier(MPI_Comm comm){
    // MPI variables
  int rank;
  int size;

    int * data;

    MPI_Status * status;

    // Loop variables
  int i;
    int a;

    int skip;

    int complete = 0;
    int currentCycle = 1;

    // Initialize MPI vars
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);

    // step 1, gathering
    while (!complete){
        skip = currentCycle * 2;

        // if currentCycle divides rank evenly, then it is a target
        if ((rank % currentCycle) == 0){
            // if skip divides rank evenly, then it needs to receive
            if ((rank % skip) == 0){
                MPI_Recv(data, 0, MPI_INT, rank + currentCycle, 99, comm, status);
                if (verbose){
                    printf("1: %d from %d\n", rank, rank + currentCycle);
                }
            // otherwise, it needs to send. Once sent, the process is done
            } else {
                if (verbose){
                    printf("1: %d to %d\n", rank, rank - currentCycle);
                }
                MPI_Send(data, 0, MPI_INT, rank - currentCycle, 99, comm);
                complete = 1;
            }
        }

        currentCycle *= 2;

        // main process will never send, so this code will allow it to complete
        if (currentCycle >= size){
            complete = 1;
        }
    }

    complete = 0;
    currentCycle = size / 2;

    // step 2, scattering

    while (!complete){
        // if currentCycle is 1, then this is the last loop
        if (currentCycle == 1){
            complete = 1;
        }

        skip = currentCycle * 2;

        // if currentCycle divides rank evenly then it is a target
        if ((rank % currentCycle) == 0){
            // if skip divides rank evenly, then it needs to send
            if ((rank % skip) == 0){
                if (verbose){
                    printf("2: %d to %d\n", rank, rank + currentCycle);
                }
                MPI_Send(data, 0, MPI_INT, rank + currentCycle, 99, comm);
            // otherwise, it needs to receive
            } else {
                if (verbose){
                    printf("2: %d waiting for %d\n", rank, rank - currentCycle);
                }
                MPI_Recv(data, 0, MPI_INT, rank - currentCycle, 99, comm, status);
                if (verbose){
                    printf("2: %d from %d\n", rank, rank - currentCycle);
                }
            }
        }

        currentCycle /= 2;
    }
}
```

## Expected behavior

The code is to increment a sum to 500, wait for all other processes to reach that point using blocking MPI_Send and MPI_Recv calls, and then increment sum to 1000.

## Observed behavior on cluster

Cluster behaves as expected

## Anomalous behavior observed on my machine

All processes in main function are reported as being 99, which I have linked specifically to the tag of the second while loop of mybarrier.

## In addition

My first draft was written with for loops, and with that one, the program executes as expected on the cluster as well, but on my machine execution never finishes, even though all processes call MPI_Finalize (but none move beyond it).

## MPI Versions

My machine is running OpenRTE 2.0.2
The cluster is running OpenRTE 1.6.3

## The questions

I have observed that my machine seems to run unexpectedly all of the time, while the cluster executes normally. This is true with other MPI code I have written as well. Was there major changes between 1.6.3 and 2.0.2 that I'm not aware of?

At any rate, I'm baffled, and I was wondering if anyone could offer some explanation as to why my machine seems to not run MPI correctly. I hope I have provided enough details, but if not, I will be happy to provide whatever additional information you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your code, maybe that's what causing the weird behavior you are seeing.

You are passing to the `MPI_Recv` routines a `status` object that hasn't been allocated. In fact, that pointer is not even initialized, so if it happens not to be `NULL`, the `MPI_Recv` will endup writing wherever in memory causing undefined behavior. The correct form is the following:

```
MPI_Status status;
...
MPI_Recv(..., &status);
```

Or if you want to use the heap:

```
MPI_Status *status = malloc(sizeof(MPI_Status));
...
MPI_Recv(..., status);
...
free(status);
```

Also since you are not using the value returned by the receive, you should instead use `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` instead:

```
MPI_Recv(..., MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

Comment: I believe that fixed it. Thanks for your help. I'm new to MPI so I'm still trying to figure out how everything works.